# Fixed sidebar overlaid by slider

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, bxslider

I'm having trouble with my fixed sidebar getting overlaid by the image gallery slider. I'm using bootstrap fixed sidebar layout and bxSlider for the image slider, I've tried using lightSlider as well. The sub menu on the sidebar always hidden under the slider layer, despite setting the sidebar z-index to 9999

Below is the code structure:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
          <div id="product-detail" class="row">
              <div class="prod-img col-md-3">
                  <ul id="bxslider">               
                    <li><img src="images/image.jpg>" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/image.jpg>" /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/image.jpg>" /></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
position: fixed;
top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
z-index: 99999;
display: block;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Hope someone can help me
Thanks a lot!

Edit: 
Here is the jsFiddle link: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/astarthe/fvzovv7o/3/)

Comment: Seems that the slider `z-index` is set higher than the sidebar. Can you reproduce the issue in the jsfiddle?

Comment: I give z-index 9999 to the sidebar div but the sub menu is still overlaid by the bxslider. If I remove the bxslider and just use image in the main content, the sub menu works ok. I've added the jsFiddle link to the issue

Comment: Give z-index:1 to bx slider and for sub menu z-index:2

Comment: @hemanjosko Doesn't work. In the jsFiddle, the sidebar and nav-sidebar has z-index: 99999, while the bxslider's parent has z-index: 1. I've tried adding z-index: 1 to #bxslider as well, but still not working